# Android Studio 3.0.1 emulators landscape mode not working

Tags: android-studio, emulation, landscape

Just upgrade from android 2.3.2 studio to android 3.0.1. studio. After i created a new application, and i tried to rotate the screen from portrait to landscape the device rotated but the screen remains in portrait mode. Please what is going on. The Compiled sdk version and target sdk version is API Level 28. I tried all the emulator and discovered that all of them behaves similarly. I have browsed the internet and discovered that android emulator 2.3 and 4.4 has a bug.

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=13189 [v2.3] https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=61671 [v4.4]

but is this still part of that bug? i also saw some solution advising that i should disable keyboard handling setting of the emulator by unchecking the "Hardware keyboard present" option.  I already uncheck the box yet this does not solve it. **please note that this is just the default application "My Application" with the default "Hello World" activity provided in android studio and not my project.** [image showing the landscape mode with the unchanged layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GXgsF.png)

Comment: Anyone figure this one out?  I am having the same issue.